# Image viewer - How to view images that are in order in the folder as clicking next in the viewer?

Tags: image-viewers

Is there a way to view images in the image viewer in order that I see them in the folder. For example if I taken 20 pictures and they are uploaded to a folder in a certain order such as time taken or saved to the folder how do I view them in the viewer if I were to click left or right to show the same order as in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

The image viewer show the images in alphabetical order. This cannot be customized, unfortunatelly. You would need to rename the pictures, for example by prepending the name with a number, in order to alphabetically sort them in the order you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there a program that can do this?

Comment: Actually, that is a separate question. Nautilus itself, at least in Ubuntu 19.10, allows to add numbers to files.

Comment: In my case, the viewer is completely unpredictable, pressing left will sometimes go right, then pressing again will move two images to the left. Horrible.

Comment: lol. this is exactly the kind of dumb thing that puts people off using Linux for regular day-to-day computing. Clicking left/right in an image viewer with the expectation that it will show the images in the same order as they are currently listed in the parent folder is like chapter 1, page 1 of UI basics. Windows gets it right! At this point I'd literally pay the developers of Directory Opus £1k from my own pocket towards developing a Linux version.